# Regex for values that are in between spaces

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and having difficulty obtaining values that are caught in between spaces.

I am trying to get the values "field 1" "abc/def try" from the sameple data below just using regex

Currently im using `(^.{18}\s+)` to skip the first 18 characters, but am at at loss of how to do grab values with spaces between.

```
A1234567890        field 1        abc/def try 
02021051812        12 test        test 12 pass
3333G132021        no test        test cancel
```

any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to be able to define how to differentiate between the two kinds of spaces. For example, is it always "exactly one space vs. more than one space", or is it "tabs vs. spaces", or "a certain number of character (including spaces) until the next column"? Without such a rule, you won't be able to solve this, I fear.

Comment: It depends on the data what to use best here. If you know the values only contain single spaces, you can use `^(\S+) +(\S+(?: \S+)*) +(\S+(?: \S+)*)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iefvgj/1/).

Comment: From the looks of it, your data fields are fixed-length. I would split the lines according to those lengths (like `^(.{18})(.{15})(.*)`), and then trim unwanted spaces from the right side of the matched groups.

Comment: If you know the person who is responsible for this poor data delivery, you should ask them to enhance it to make it machine readable (JSON, XML, etc)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the help, this worked best considering the chance of non fix length!

Answer (score 0):

If this text has fixed-width columns, you can match and trim the column values knowing the amount of chars between start of string and the column text.

For example, this regex will work for the text you posted:

```php
^(.*?)\s*(?<=.{19})(.*?)\s*(?<=^.{34})(.*?)\s*(?<=^.{46})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LVbqsB/1/).

So, Column 2 starts at Position 19, Column 3 starts at Position 34 and Column 4 (end of string here) is at Position 46.

However, this regex is not that efficient,  and it would be really great if the data format is fixed on the provider's side.

Answer (score 0):

Given the not knowing if the data is always the same length I created the following, which will provide you with a group per column you might want to use:

```
^((\s{0,1}\S{1,})*)(\s{2,})((\s{0,1}\S{1,})*)(\s{2,})((\s{0,1}\S{1,})*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2rNX4D/1)